# Combining matches with FILTER in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I want to match two terms at once in a FILTER but the && operator returns no results while there should be two. I am looking for the keywords "industrie" and "omzet" appearing together with one dataset.

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dcat: <http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT ?dataset ?dataset_name ?keyword
WHERE {  
  ?dataset rdf:type dcat:Dataset .
  ?dataset dct:title ?dataset_name .         
  ?dataset dcat:keyword ?term . 
  ?term skos:prefLabel ?keyword .  
  FILTER (STRSTARTS(?keyword,"industrie") && STRSTARTS(?keyword,"omzet"))  
} 
ORDER BY ?dataset_name
```

I checked the results with the || operator which works as expected and gives 368 results. Among the results are two datasets which contain the two wanted keywords. Like this.

```
dataset dataset_name    keyword
1       "ab"            "omzet" 
1       "ab"            "industrie"
2       "xy"            "omzet"
2       "xy"            "industrie"
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue with your query is that you use the same variable `?keyword` in both statements.
A string cannot start with *both* "industrie" and "omzet".

What you need to do is this instead:

```
SELECT ?dataset ?dataset_name ?keyword1 ?keyword2
WHERE {  
  ?dataset rdf:type dcat:Dataset .
  ?dataset dct:title ?dataset_name .         
  ?dataset dcat:keyword ?term . 
  ?term skos:prefLabel ?keyword1, ?keyword2 .  
  FILTER (STRSTARTS(?keyword1,"industrie") && STRSTARTS(?keyword2,"omzet"))  
} 
ORDER BY ?dataset_name
```

Comment: Thanks, Valerio, but this didn't give results either. But it made me think. The dcat:keyword holds a list of keyword uri's. They have to be mapped to several skos:prefLabels. So, this works.

Comment: Makes sense. Well done for finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ?dataset ?dataset_name ?keyword1 ?keyword2
WHERE {  
  ?dataset rdf:type dcat:Dataset .
  ?dataset dct:title ?dataset_name .        
  ?dataset dcat:keyword ?term1,?term2 . 
  ?term1 skos:prefLabel ?keyword1 .
  ?term2 skos:prefLabel ?keyword2 .  
    FILTER (STRSTARTS(?keyword1,"industrie") && STRSTARTS(?keyword2,"omzet"))  
}      

ORDER BY ASC(?dataset_name)
```